# Combine two fields into one

Tags: javascript

Thanks guys

My field 1 is Name and Field 2 is Surname. Field 3 is CombinedNameSurname

Is this the correct way I do it?

```
</Center>
<html> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function copy() 
{ 
    var Field1 = document.getElementById("Name"); 
    var Field2 = document.getElementById("Surname"); 
    var Field3 = document.getElementById("CombinedNameSurname"); 
    Field3.value = Field1.value + Field2.value 
    Field1.value = ''                                                                   //Reset value to ''
    Field3.value = ''                                                                  //Reset value to ''
} 
</script> 
<input type="button" value="Add Qualification" onClick="copy();" /> 
</html>
```

Thanks so much for the help

Marius

Comment: You may be resetting the wrong Field.

Comment: Obviously not...you set value of `Field3` and 2 lines later reset it

Comment: Also, you're going to end up mangling names, "Steve" "Smith" will become "SteveSmith".

Comment: Did any of the given answers provide a solution for you? if so please feel free to mark them as such and give a upvote to the people who take the effort to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As `gurvinder372` statet you are resetting the wrong Field. You should correct your code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function copy() 
    { 
        var Field1 = document.getElementById("Name"); 
        var Field2 = document.getElementById("Surname"); 
        var Field3 = document.getElementById("CombinedNameSurname"); 

        Field3.value = Field1.value + Field2.value;
        Field1.value = ''; //Reset value to ''
       //wrong: Field3.value = '';
       //correct
       Field2.value = ''; //Reset value to ''
} 
</script>
```

**First you called** `Field3.value = Field1.value + Field2.value;` **to have a combined string inside** `Field3` **but then resetted all the content to '' by calling** `Field3.value = '';`

P.S.: *Please for future programming: although javascript allows it (under certain conditions) you should not forget to put semicolons* `;`.

Comment: If you're curious when those semicolon rules apply, you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion).

Answer (score 0):

Given these examples,

```
 var Field1 = 'John'
 var Field2 = 'Smith'
```

If you're looking for `JohnSmith` as your `Field3`, then your above code is fine.

However, if you want `John Smith`, I would add a space between the two variables like so:

```
Field3 = Field1 + ' ' + Field2
```

I'm wondering why you're resetting `Field3` after you've just set it?
Perhaps you want to reset `Field1` and `Field2` instead?

```
Field3.value = Field1.value + ' ' + Field2.value 
Field1.value = ''                                                                   
Field2.value = ''
```